# How to create a file in another directory of different path while performing git log in ruby script

Tags: ruby, git, git-log

Please find the code below.

```
Dir.chdir('/home/user/Source/pxe/')do
system("git log "+ version_one +" " + version_two +" --pretty=format:'%h %ad%x09%an%x09%s' --date=short", :out => ['gitlog.txt', 'a'])
end
```

Depending on version inputs from user, I perform `git log` between two versions and log gets saved in `gitlog.txt` of pxe folder.

Now my question is, how to create this `gitlog.txt` in another directory and append the log to the same file, say the new file path is: `/home/user/server-diff/gitlog.txt`

I tried it in below way but no file got written and raised an error on execution 
`Permission denied- /home/user/server-diff/gitlog.txt (Errno::EACCES)`:

```
file = File.new("/home/user/server-diff/gitlog.txt", "w")
Dir.chdir('/home/user/Source/pxe/')do
    system("git log "+ version_one +" " + version_two +" --pretty=format:'%h %ad%x09%an%x09%s' --date=short", :out => [file, 'a'])
    end
```

Please let me know how to go ahead, I have one more question associated with this.

Kindly let me know if there is any lack of clarity in the question asked.

Comment: Does "didn't work" mean no file got written, or that it did get written but it overwrote the file instead of appending?

Comment: @Dylan. no file got written.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up two ways to use a file in the `system` call. You can either use a file object beforehand (making sure to open it in "append" mode instead of "write" mode) and then just pass that object to `system` without an `"a"`:

```
file = File.new("/home/user/server-diff/gitlog.txt", "a")
Dir.chdir('/home/user/Source/pxe/')do
  system("git log "+ version_one +" " + version_two +" --pretty=format:'%h %ad%x09%an%x09%s' --date=short", :out => file)
end
```

Or you can get rid of the `file = ...` line altogether and pass the filename to `system`, keeping the `"a"` option:

```
Dir.chdir('/home/user/Source/pxe/')do
  system("git log "+ version_one +" " + version_two +" --pretty=format:'%h %ad%x09%an%x09%s' --date=short", :out => ["/home/user/server-diff/gitlog.txt", "a"])
end
```

Also, you'll want to make sure the directory you're writing into exists:

```
Dir.mkdir("/home/user/server-diff") unless Dir.exists?("/home/user/server-diff")
```

And if you're getting a Permission Denied error, you'll want to make sure you actually have write permissions to the folder (and file if it already exists).